# Pass Data from Array of objects by ID Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

i have 2 .vue pages ( List,Details)
now in List i list Array of Objects like this i get them from API

> `[{...},{...},{...}]`

and i display it in the List using v-for

and i have Details button in each list of them

when i click on Details, i route with the ID of the object to Details page

i can print the ID in console and i could print it in the `.vue` 
using : `$this.route.params.ID;`

but i cant get other data where ID =  `$this.route.params.ID;`

I HAVE BEEN TRYING FOR 3 DAYS...

```html
 <div
  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 pa-4 ma-4"
  v-for="(cmpd, index) in Compounds"
  :key="cmpd.id"
>
  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    :flat="flat"
    :loading="loading"
    :outlined="outlined"
    :elevation="elevation"
    :raised="raised"
  >
    <v-img
      v-if="media"
      class="white--text"
      height="250px"
              >
      <v-card-title class="align-end fill-height">
        {{cmpd.name}} ({{cmpd.city}})
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'CompoundDetails', params: { CompoundID: 
   cmpd.id }}">
          <v-btn text>Details</v-btn>
        </router-link>
      </v-card-title>
    </v-img>
    <v-card-title v-else>{{cmpd.name}}</v-card-title>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show your router file

Comment: {
      path: "/CompoundDetails/:CompoundID",
      name: "CompoundDetails",
      component: CompoundDetails
    },

Comment: I think you've got the wrong path... 

`/list/:CompoundID`

Since you're coming from List Page

Comment: Vuetify also provides :to prop on v-card, so that instead of router-link

Comment: Your param is named `CompoundID`, **not** `ID` so you should be using `this.$route.params.CompoundID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're passing the ID with `CompoundID: cmpd.id`. But you want all of the object and information, right? So why not pass the whole object? `params: { Compound: cmpd }`. Then you'd have the whole object.

And just in case you're using Vuex, you can put it in the store as well for access from anywhere.